# python slow to check if mongodb record found

Tags: performance, mongodb, python-3.x

I have a python (3.2) request that goes to MongoDB and the request itself is running fast enough. When I then perform an if statement check to see if any records were found it takes 50 times as long:

```
    Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    58         27623      6475988    234.4      1.7          itemInDB = db.mainData.find({"x":item[x]}).limit(1)
    59                                           
    60                                                       #existing item in db
    61         27623    293419802  10622.3     77.6          if itemInDB.count():
```

What on earth is the cause for that if statement taking so long?! I presume there must be a better way to check if a record was found but google has come up empty.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

### Perhaps a Better Way

If you're only interested in returning one value, you might want to use `find_one` instead of `find`. It will stop looking for values after one has been found, as opposed to `find`, which has to run through the collection:

```
itemInDB = db.mainData.find_one({"x":item[x]})
if itemInDB:
  print("Item found")
else:
  print("Item not found")
```

### For Your Example

According to [the PyMongo docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.count), when querying the count of a cursor, you can pass in a parameter (`True` or `False`) to take into account any `skip` or `limit` calls previously made to the cursor. The default for that parameter is `False` (namely, not taking those calls into account). That may be affecting the performance of your `count` query.

### Gauging Query Performance

If you want to see how your query will be carried out by mongo, you can call [`explain`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) on your cursor:

```
db.coll.find({"x":4}).explain()
```

The explain function is also [implemented in PyMongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.explain).

Comment: findOne apparently is worse than find().limit(1) which I implemented prior and actually made it run 3 seconds slower (the code is in a loop of around 30k iterations)
Limits had no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to the find() function and not the if statement. I created an index on "x" (as I should have anyway). Changed the find to find_one and removed the .count() from the if statement. Overall 75% faster.